# Download public google drive files

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a problem with google drive.

Before the link:

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID

Worked fine until now, :-( but now it does not work anymore. The result is not found error 404, but the file exists. I could upload file and easily build to download url.

For example this, public document.

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Hz4D52yKS0qPIUrMmeYzEl_16UpdPrGhJAwSV_EaM4Y

The document exist.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Hz4D52yKS0qPIUrMmeYzEl_16UpdPrGhJAwSV_EaM4Y/edit

How can I download files without authorization, i need direct link.

Thanks!!!

Comment: I don't think this works anymore it links back to the Google drive no longer hosts web files.

Comment: Google has surely made some changes. What is the way now? How can I build a direct link to download documents.

Answer (score 7):

The download url works for **files** in Drive. e.g. https://docs.google.com/uc?id=FILE_ID

The problem is that you are trying to download a "Google document" not a file.

To download a Google document you can use the [`File export`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export) method. Typically, you can download the Google doc in any of the formats listed in the UI menu `File > Download as...` options.

Comment: Good answer thanks!!!, I do not knew this. And how I can download the "google Docs". Is there any way?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I notice you've asked a few questions but not accepted any answers, ever. You should check out [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: I follow searching the solution.With the api I could not make it yet. I need to connect my own server to googleapi without client event. I must downlod file without client auth in google. It could I need gsuit for this? THANKS!!!+

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```html
require_once '../autoload.php';
$user_to_impersonate = 'XXXXXXXXX';
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='. __DIR__ .'/service-account.json');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client_email   = 'XXXX@XXXX.com'; 
$client->setSubject($client_email); 
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')); 
$driveservice = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
//var_dump($driveservice);
$parameters = array();
if (isset($pageToken)) {
  $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
}
$files = $driveservice->files->listFiles($parameters);
$fileId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$file = $driveservice->files->export($fileId, 'application/pdf', array(
  'alt' => 'media' ));
$size     = $file->getBody()->getSize();
$content  = $file->getBody()->read($size);
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"XXXX.pdf\"");
echo $content;
```

Comment: https://milanaryal.com/direct-linking-to-your-files-on-dropbox-google-drive-and-onedrive/